# Are there incompatibility risks when updating Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, updates

I was just checking if any installed programs required an update and I realized that the latest LTS version of Node.js is 12.13.1 while I have 10.16.0 installed.

I was wondering if there are incompatibility risks when updating Node. When searching on Google I can't find anything about it breaking code or even being safe (safe as in, it doesn't break anything).
I know this is a pretty dumb question, but I would really appreciate an answer.

Comment: it really depends on what your dependencies are. I have custom built packages and also use oracle which break if I upgrade to node12.

Comment: A little bit of risk, but not too much. The correct thing to do here is to create tests for your code and make sure they all pass after the update. If they don't, you should roll back node or adjust the code for the update.

Comment: Well, i have created a branch and started trying to make it work, i had a painless upgrade experience. Go for it.